# Comparing columns to check if they are the same of different

Tags: r

I am trying to compare columns to compare the different values in two columns. I thought this was going to be straight forwards but I am running into an issue that I can't seem to figure out. What I am trying to do is just compare two columns, each column has the size of files. The first column is the size of a file in database a and the second column is the size of the same file in database b. Here is the code I an running to compare the columns.

```
df$ready.to.delete <- ifelse(df$V1.x > df$V1.y, 'FALSE',
                                                   ifelse(df$V1.x < df$V1.y, 'TRUE', 'TIE'))
```

For whatever reason, sometimes when column `V1.y` is larger than `V1.x` the values get marked as `FALSE`. On the flip side, sometimes when `V1.x` is larger than `V1.y` the values get marked as `TRUE`. I have no idea what is going on here. Here is an example of my data frame. It might be easier to work with/understand what I am talking about if you see it.

```
df <- structure(list(V1.x = c("1449", "1449", "1449", "1449", "1449", 
"64903263796", "11955", "46480455130", "49692901057", "11977", 
"733441", "793914", "35752752006", "705220", "916127", "6483602181"
), V1.y = c("1449", "1449", "1449", "1449", "1449", "8235617", 
"46058278195", "7459346", "7451650", "49743769176", "54429092612", 
"63543035754", "1024458", "118130416321", "117244583843", "4463704"
), ready.to.delete = c("TIE", "TIE", "TIE", "TIE", "TIE", "TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", 
"FALSE", "FALSE")), .Names = c("V1.x", "V1.y", "ready.to.delete"
), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your columns are `character` and are being evaluated as such:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric),
         ready.to.delete = case_when(V1.x > V1.y ~ "FALSE",
                                     V1.x < V1.y ~ "TRUE",
                                     TRUE ~ "TIE"))
```

This gives us:

```
          V1.x         V1.y ready.to.delete
1         1449         1449             TIE
2         1449         1449             TIE
3         1449         1449             TIE
4         1449         1449             TIE
5         1449         1449             TIE
6  64903263796      8235617           FALSE
7        11955  46058278195            TRUE
8  46480455130      7459346           FALSE
9  49692901057      7451650           FALSE
10       11977  49743769176            TRUE
11      733441  54429092612            TRUE
12      793914  63543035754            TRUE
13 35752752006      1024458           FALSE
14      705220 118130416321            TRUE
15      916127 117244583843            TRUE
16  6483602181      4463704           FALSE
```

Here's an example of what is going on:

```
df <- data.frame(numbers_as_characters = c("9", "100000"))

df %>% 
  mutate(max_value = ifelse(numbers_as_characters == max(numbers_as_characters), T, F))

  numbers_as_characters max_value
1                     9      TRUE
2                100000     FALSE
```

Comment: Ahh yes, that works perfectly. For whatever reason, at some point I change those columns to characters. I think it was because I had `NA`s in some of them. I just replaced the `NA`s with zeros and what you wrote and what I wrote both worked perfectly.